# TCP server only accepts the message from one iOS device at a time

Tags: c#, tcp

I use c# to create a TCP server to connect to the iOS devices. However, I've found that it can only accept one iOS device at a time. I couldn't figure out what is the problem. Can anyone have a look and see what is the problem?

```
            IPAddress ipadr = IPAddress.Parse(localIP);
            System.Net.IPEndPoint EndPoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(ipadr, 8060);
            newsock.Bind(EndPoint);
            newsock.Listen(10);
            client = newsock.Accept();
            IPEndPoint clientip = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
            while (true)
            {
                if (!isDisConnected)
                {
                data = new byte[1024];
                recv = client.Receive(data);
                if (recv == 0)
                    break;
                string receivedText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
            }
            client.Close();
            newsock.Close();
```

Comment: After `client = newsock.Accept();` create a thread, delegate the rest of work to it and call Accept again. Using Async method `newsock.BeginAccept` can be another alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two kinds of sockets: The socket that you use to listen (it is never connected) and the sockets that correspond to connections (each socket represents one connection).

Accept returns you a connected socket to the client that was just accepted. Each call to Accept accepts a new, independent client.

If you want to handle more than one client at a time (which is almost always required) you must ensure that a call to Accept is pending at all times so that new clients can be accepted.

A simple model to achieve this is to accept in a loop forever and start a thread for each client that you accepted:

```
while (true) {
 var clientSocket = listeningSocket.Accept();
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() => HandleClient(clientSocket));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at AcceptAsync.  Each accept operation allows one connection, so you have to call Accept again.  AcceptAsync works asychronously and avoids the difficulties of having to create delegates or threads.

The general model is:

Accept operation completes
Hand off AcceptSocket to code that will Receive data asychronously from that socket.
Call Accept again to listen for more clients.

The same principle also works if you want to do synchronous receives.

Check out this question: [Server design using SocketAsyncEventArgs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538348/server-design-using-socketasynceventargs)

Comment: Making Accept async is the wrong idea and I don't even see how this would solve the problem. He needs to make everything *after* Accept async and not block the next Accept.

Comment: I very clearly said that he should hand data off to an asychronous receive.  As for the first part, he doesn't NEED async, but it also doesn't hurt to use it either.  If he said, "I only have 1 user an hour" then yes, it would be the wrong approach to use AcceptAsync because there wouldn't be any need to handle accept operations in rapid succession.

Comment: You make valid points here. Basically, you need to have multiple accept calls outstanding only if a single thread can no longer keep up with all the new incoming clients (like 100k per second or so). And after that point it is unclear if the network stack is even capable of utilizing multiple threads to process accept calls on the same socket.